# Probability question involving 4 coins (gold and silver) in 3 boxes each. Is my explanation correct?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Key:
g = Gold coin.
s = Silver coin.

Box A)
g1
g2
g3
g4
Box B)
g5
g6
s5
s6
Box C)
s1
s2
s3
s4

Waz chooses a box at random and picks up a coin from it. It turns out to be a gold coin.
( Pick 1 from Box ? results in: g being picked )

Question 1:
Which box do you think g (pick 1) is more likely to have been picked from?

My explanation (answer 1):
Box C is impossible. Box A has more g than Box B, so Box A is more likely.
Box A: **4/8 or 1/2**
Box B: **2/8 or 1/4**

Question 2: For pick 2 from that same Box ?, which do you think is more likely to be picked by Waz: g or s?

My explanation (answer 2):
Pick 1 establishes Box C is impossible leaving 8 possibilities. However, since one g has been taken out of the equation, this now leaves only **7 possibilities.
5/7 = g and 2/7 = s.**
Hence pick 2 is more likely to be g than s.

**Is my probability calculation correct here? (bolded parts)**

A1: Box A: 1/2 , Box B: 1/4
A2: I think it's either 5/7 = g or 4/6 = g and 2/7 = s or 2/6 = s.
I'm not sure.
Are there only 7 possibilities or 6 remaining for pick 2? Or something else?

Comment: *Is my probability correct here?*  Which probability? to which question?  You don't even know what your answer is, so how can anyone tell you whether you are correct, or not?

Comment: I've put it in bold. I don't know if my answers are correct. I think my explanation (calculations) are wrong. Hence, I want somebody to explain to me the correct reasoning to get the answer for both questions.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general reasoning/intuition is correct, but your calculations are not.

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ represent the events that the box selected was $A$, $B$, or $C$ respectively.  Let $G$ represent the event that the first drawn coin was gold.

Then we are asked to compute and compare $\Pr[A \mid G]$, $\Pr[B \mid G]$, and $\Pr[C \mid G]$; these are the conditional probabilities that the selected box was $A$, $B$, or $C$ given the drawn coin was gold.  We have from Bayes' rule

$$\Pr[A \mid G] = \frac{\Pr[G \mid A]\Pr[A]}{\Pr[G]}.$$

Since before drawing a coin from the box, each box is equally likely to have been selected, we know $\Pr[A] = \Pr[B] = \Pr[C] = 1/3$.  We also know that $\Pr[G \mid A] = 1$ because every coin in box $A$ is gold.  The only unresolved quantity is $\Pr[G]$, the *unconditional* probability of drawing a gold coin.  Our intuition suggests that since among all three boxes, there are an equal number of gold and silver coins, that we should have $\Pr[G] = 1/2$.  Indeed, this is true as the law of total probability demonstrates:

$$\begin{align}
\Pr[G] &= \Pr[G \mid A]\Pr[A] + \Pr[G \mid B]\Pr[B] + \Pr[G \mid C]\Pr[C] \\
&= (1)(1/3) + (1/2)(1/3) + (0)(1/3) \\
&= 1/2.
\end{align}$$

So the desired probability is $$\Pr[A \mid G] = \frac{1/3}{1/2} = \frac{2}{3}.$$  Similarly,

$$\Pr[B \mid G] = \frac{\Pr[G \mid B]\Pr[B]}{\Pr[G]} = \frac{(1/2)(1/3)}{1/2} = \frac{1}{3},$$

and of course

$$\Pr[C \mid G] = \frac{\Pr[G \mid C]\Pr[C]}{\Pr[G]} = \frac{(0)(1/3)}{1/2} = 0.$$

This formally proves that the most likely box from which the gold coin was drawn is box $A$, but the probability is $2/3$, not $1/2$ as you asserted.

For the second coin drawn from the same box, again intuition suggests that this coin should also be gold, since $A$ was the more likely box (twice as likely as $B$) that was selected.  If we let $G'$ be the event that the second coin drawn (without replacement) is gold, then we are asked to compute $\Pr[G' \mid G]$, the probability of the second coin being gold given that the first coin was gold.  Thus,

$$\Pr[G' \mid G] = \Pr[G' \mid A, G]\Pr[A \mid G] + \Pr[G' \mid B, G]\Pr[B \mid G].$$  We omit box $C$ since $\Pr[C \mid G] = 0$.  Then

$$\Pr[G' \mid A, G] = 1,$$

since if the first gold coin was drawn from box $A$, the second coin will necessarily be gold.  But

$$\Pr[G' \mid B, G] = \frac{1}{3},$$

since if the first gold coin was drawn from box $B$, there remains only $1$ gold coin out of $3$ in that box.  Therefore,

$$\Pr[G' \mid G] = (1)(2/3) + (1/3)(1/3) = \frac{7}{9}.$$

Note how the calculation must match the sampling process.  Your calculation is incorrect because you seem to be allowing the second coin to be selected from a different box as the first, when the problem clearly states that once the first coin is drawn, the second draw is from the same box.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I watched this video: https://youtu.be/ytfCdqWhmdg?t=637 - I understood the answer, but I knew I didn't know the correct explanation regarding the calculation (the video doesn't explain any further either). Hence I posted a more obvious/ bigger example to see what the correct/more detailed explanation would be.